# Will or regular oil help increase oil pressure than synthetic oil?

Tags: oil, pressure

Will regular oil help increase oil pressure in my engine than synthetic oil?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In a word: no. If you are using the same weight of dino oil vs synthetic, it will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: Checking and refurbishing the oil pump will probably be effective though.